# Generate Java files from wsdl due to more than one part bound to body

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I using a third party wsdl file from Airarabia

[WSDL Link](http://reservations.airarabia.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl)

it gives me error

```
[WARNING] Ignoring operation "book": more than one part bound to body
  line 5301 of http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "getReservationbyPNR": more than one part bound to body
  line 5157 of http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "modifyResQuery": more than one part bound to body
  line 5285 of http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

[WARNING] Ignoring operation "modifyReservation": more than one part bound to body
  line 5295 of http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl

[WARNING] Non unique body parts! In a port, as per BP 1.1 R2710 operations must have unique operation signature on the wire for successful dispatch. In port AAResWebServicesHttpPort, Operations "getSSRDetails" and "getUserDefinedSSRDetails" have the same request body block {http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05}AA_OTA_AirSSRDetailsRQ. Method dispatching may fail, runtime will try to dispatch using SOAPAction
  line 5959 of http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl
```

i have used bindings methods and did try various ways.

Any help...

Comment: any success on this?

Comment: No, i add to use Apache Axis 1.1 and then apache HTTP to send the request.